# How do I increase the limit of 100 cards shown in the Rally Kanban Column?

Tags: javascript, rally, kanban

We use the Rally Kanban to show user stories (US) that are tagged with a custom field and in a specific iteration.  Currently there are 104 us that meet this criteria but only 100 show on the Kanban.

The help states that there is a 100 limit.

How do I increase that limit?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've likely customized the Kanban app with some additional functionality and are running in a Custom HTML panel.  Cool.  You should be able to set the maximum number of cards by passing in maxCardsPerColumn when you create your CardBoard.

http://developer.help.rallydev.com/card-board

```
var cardboardConfig = {
    //..other configs
    maxCardsPerColumn: 200
    //..other configs
};
```

Comment: Kyle,  I just tested this your suggestion and it works great!  Thank You